# Execute a method when I click on the screen

Tags: android

I need execute a method every time I click any part of the screen. I have tried to do this with a `AcessibilityService`, but I have to activate it on settings. I have also tried  to do with a `BroadcastReceiver`, but it doesn't work. Any idea to do it?

Answer (score 2):

As long as you want to do it within your own Activity, simply override `onTouch()`.

If you want to do this across the entire device, it is not possible through the public SDK, and you will have to customize Android at a source level.